# Starting .jar with cmd or batch

Tags: java, batch-file, jar

I got my "EntityGenerator.jar" but if I type

```
java -jar EntityGenerator.jar
```

in the command line I got this:

> Unable to access to enter jarfile EntityGenerator

or when I type this:

```
java EntityGenerator
```

this error comes up:

> Main class could not be found or loaded

also I want to execute this by having a batch file.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Are you running that first command from the location of the jar?

Comment: uhm to be honest i dont know, i never used the console that much...i was just told to type this in to start the program, the person who told me is now in holiday and i'm sitting here with the Error.

Comment: OK lets say this is the location of the jar `C:/elipseworkspace/myproject/dist/myproject.jar`. From the command line, you need to `cd` (change directory) to `dist`, in order to use just the name of the jar, as you are doing. Alternatively, you could just do `java -jar C:/elipseworkspace/myproject/dist/myproject.jar`, using the absolute path

Comment: okay i now used the full path but there are now a raaaaange of (i think) program intern errors like JDOM Errors and stuff, so i'll talk to them now, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- try to provide the full path of the jar.
- In order to create a batch
  file, just put the command inside a text file and rename that file to have
  ".bat" suffix

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it was easier than i thought!
I just didnt read right, he couldn't find the XML File.
Now that i placed them together it works fine!